# Type mismatch, conflicting macros

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

The first VBA script I have is working fine,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C9:G9,C15:G15,C21:G21,C27,G27")) _
  Is Nothing) Then
    With Target
        If Not .HasFormula Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Value = UCase(.Value)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

This makes all text entered in a cell capitalize after entered by user

Then I have a macro button to clear certain cells

```
Sub inputcaps()
Range("C9", "G9").Value = ""
End Sub
```

After pressing this macro it works fine, but I do get a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error and the first script stops working and I have to restart the excel sheet.

How can I fix this??

The debug takes me to .Value = UCase(.Value) from the first script

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to do following this code:-**

Not More Issue in code simple First **EnableEvents  = false** and before finished march write **EnableEvents = true**

Like this Code :

```
 Sub inputcaps()
   Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("C9", "G9").Value = ""

   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[vba](/questions/tagged/vba)  [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)   [mayurpathak](/questions/tagged/mayurpathak)